# How to create multiple image cropper in Xamrin.Forms?

Tags: image, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I want to achieve following functionality. Can anybody please suggest me any way or example that can be work worthy in iOS and Android. However, the priority is of iOS.

I have a page where user can upload 8 pictures. I want to provide multiple image selection. User can select 8 pictures together or user can select in group like 2-3 pictures. Even user can select only one picture.

Now the twist that I want to provide image cropper option. Let say user have selected 5 picture. After selecting pictures, I want to show image cropper screen with `Next` button. So, user must be able to crop all 5 image one by one with one go. `Next` button will show to next image to crop. At 5th image, there will be `Done` button that will take user back to image gallery which will show all 5 pictures.

Comment: This question is way to broad for SO. If you have a question on how to accomplish a specific action (e.g. crop a bitmap using C#), show the work you've already done and explain where you're stuck.